# Как узнать тип элементов вектора?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, типы-данных

К примеру есть вектор:

```
vector<int> alfa;
```

как узнать тип его элементов до появления первого элемента. Типа:

```
decltype(alfa[0]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотреть на `<int>` в скобках :)

Вообще-то `decltype` не вычисляет само выражение, так что до появления элемента использовать `alfa[0]` можно, но... Это будет ссылка.

Я бы делал так:

```
decay_t<decltype(alfa[0])> b;
```

Но не проще ли для вектора (и прочих стандартных контейнеров) использовать его `value_type`?

Comment: конечно проще value_type

Comment: я не знал про value_type - поэтому и спрашиваю. А как его задать? Всмысле взять?

Comment: Если через переменную - типа `decltype(alfa)::value_type c;`

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<int>::value_type b;
```

Answer (score 1):

Для примера определим версию функции вывода содержания STL контейнера:

```
template <class V>
void show(V v)
{
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<typename V::value_type>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

`std::ostream_iterator` в аргументе шаблона должен иметь тип элементов контейнера. 
 При использовании не важно какого типа контейнер и какого типа его элементы...

```
int main()
{   
    std::vector<int> v1{1, 2};
    std::vector<std::string> v2 {"first", "second"};
    show(v1);
    show(v2);
    return 0;
}
```